# Can you have too many variables in a header?

Tags: c++, boolean

I kept getting runtime errors at one spot of my code and narrowed it down to a bool that was initialized to 205. I looked this issue up and that's apparently garbage that an uninitialized bool can have.

Okay, but I initialized it. This boolean value is in the private section of the header file. The class contains a method to set the value and another to return the value. Pretty bog standard stuff. So I set up a quick little test.

```
thing.setValue(false);
cout << thing.getValue() <<endl;
```

(not the actual names, but just to keep it simple)
It still spit out 205. Literally one statement setting the variable, then the very next simply asking to repeat it back and it's giving me garbage.

Somewhat perplexed, I took a look at the header file. There's an `int` declared right above the `bool` in the header, so I did a similar test with that one. It works just fine. I swap the order of the two in the header. Now the `bool` works and the `int` doesn't. So there's one `vector<int>` in the header above the two that it turns out I'm no longer using because I've replaced the method that used it. So I delete that, lo and behold it now works.

I can't seem to find any information on this. I imagine it's likely I just don't know what to search for to find the answer. I'm hoping it's a really obvious and dumb mistake someone more experienced can slap me over the head with so I can move on.

For code example, it's just a simple header file like any other that looks like

```
#ifndef concept_H
#define concept_H
class concept {
private:
    //...
    //...
    //...
    int x;
    bool y;
public:
    //bunch of methods//
    void setY(bool whatever);
    bool isY();
};
#endif
```

with the method implementation being equally trivial

```
void concept::setY(bool whatever){
    y=whatever;
}
bool concept::isY(){
    return y;
}
```

This isn't the actual code; there's a lot of other stuff there on the periphery and I just don't know what to include as relevant. Hoping again that it's a dumb mistake I'm making and someone can just tell me right away, but if not I can provide more. I just need help to even know where to begin to look.

Comment: Sounds like maybe the header and implementation files are using different alignment settings, so the `bool` variable is not located at the correct offset within the class where the implementation is expecting it to be.

Comment: You'll need to provide a [MCVE]. This is probably undefined behavior somewhere else.

Comment: It seems likely that the problem exists when you keep the vector member and it's being corrupted instead of the `bool`, though you don't see a problem since you don't use it. Removing the vector probably bumps up the `bool` to take occupy the memory the vector used to occupy and is now the casualty of whatever UB you have.

Comment: Your bug(s) are probably elsewhere in your code (heap or stack corruption). Try using valgrind or sanitizers (don't know if VC has those, might be worth trying clang just for that if it has them on Windows).

Comment: Check the address of the member in both places it's used, as you walk through in the debugger. If you can, set a watchpoint on it and see if something else is trampling the memory. To put your mind at ease: there definitely isn't a limit on the number of variables or members. Something else is going on. (valgrind or sanitizers definitely worth using if available)

Comment: *"bool that was initialized to 205"* ?!

Comment: Your question title doesn't fit your question.  To answer the *title* of your question, there is a limit to the quantity of variables inside a class.  Also, prefer not to declare or define variables {globally} in a header file.

Comment: Consider implementing stuff that is *necessary*.  Some relevant code or data fields may be relevant but never accessed.

Comment: I really appreciate everyone who chimed in. A little bit of help goes a long ways.

Answer (score 2):

No, there is no set limit on the number of variables you can declare.  That is not the cause of your issue.

Comment: Why the downvote? This is clearly a correct answer :-)

Comment: "The sky is blue" is also correct, and also not useful. This is a long question. Answers need to address more than the title.